# Disable 'New' Button

Tags: trigger, lightning, lightning-community

I have a requirement on a partner community, where I have a Flow to create records on an object name 'Forms'. But I have a list view on the same page where a 'New' button need to hide or disable based on profile. It is not possible in object setting since I have to create records through flow. But I don't want some profile user to create by pressing 'New' Button. How do I accomplish this use case.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to:

1. Remove the "Create" permission for the community user from the permission set(s) and/or profile
2. Ensure the flow runs in System Mode so it ignores the user's CRUD and FLS permissions.

The latter is achieved by opening the flow in the Flow Builder, clicking the cog (1) and clicking "Show Advanced" button (2 appears), then select a different How to Run the Flow option:

[image: Example flow]

Comment: It works. Thanks.

Comment: I have one more question. On my Partner Portal, I have a 'Forms' list view. When I press the item in list view, it open the detail but I can't see anything under the 'Related' item. What should I do. It is only happening on the above mentioned 'Forms' object. Please note that this 'Forms' object has a "Record types"

Comment: Hi @VinuVarghese best if you raise that as a separate question in SFSE.

Comment: I did separately